# php script to analyze files

Tags: php, regex, linux, bash, scripting

I have some db log file , i want to monitor using a php script. The logs are produces daily and i want to be able to monitor if today's db log file was created. The come out in the following format:

```
1.xxx_2017-05-05_00h30m.Friday.sql.gz
2. xxx_2017-05-08_00h30m.Monday.sql.gz
3. xxx_2017-05-09_00h30m.Tuesday.sql.gz
```

Using php, how can i check if today's file e.g (xxx_2017-05-09_00h30m.Tuesday.sql.gz), the script will be running daily to check the current day files.

Any ideas ?

Comment: Use [**`glob()`**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php)

Answer (score 0):

Use `preg_match` `/(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})/`  Loop the file names

```
      <?php

     $dateArray = preg_match("/(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})/", 'xxx_2017-05-05_00h30m.Friday.sql.gz', $match);

     if($match[0]==date('Y-m-d'))
     {
         echo "today log file exists";

     }else{
         echo "today don't have any log files";
     }

    ?>
```

Comment: Thanks, i will have to expand it, as i have these log files in different folders, like: /mnt/back, /mnt/sa, mnt/con. These logs are in all these folders.

Comment: if my answer is useful mark it with green tick it's useful for future user reference @sawe

Answer (score 0):

As said in the comments, you could use `glob()` in combination with a regular expression:

```
<?php
$regex = '_' . date("Y-m-d") . '_';
foreach (glob($regex) as $filename) {
    echo "$filename" . "\n";
}
?>
```